# Reconstruction of a signal based on non-uniform samples and a well below nyquist sampling rate

Tags: matlab, nyquist, nonuniform

I have a set of non-uniform samples that are the following set of data over the course of 1 second:

[image]

The rightmost column is in milliseconds, and the first three leftmost columns are each different signals which are sampled at that given point in time.

Each of these signals are measuring a 60hz signal, but as you'll notice, the sensor is only measuring 20 measurements per second, which is well below nyquist. Additionally, you'll notice that the samples don't have the same amount time between them.

I can improve the sensor to get it above Nyquist, but I am wondering if there is any use at all in messing with my currently collected data to reconstruct a 60hz waveform and determine an amplitude for the wave.

Here's the readings as text:

```
 -18.61   4.31 -41.61 1615576499.00 27758856.00
 -18.14   2.85 -42.17 1615576499.00 27758909.00
 -18.46   1.46 -41.33 1615576499.00 27758962.00
 -18.30   1.58 -39.83 1615576499.00 27759015.00
 -18.84   3.48 -38.80 1615576499.00 27759069.00
 -18.85   4.05 -40.40 1615576499.00 27759122.00
 -18.34   4.00 -41.27 1615576499.00 27759175.00
 -18.63   2.76 -42.11 1615576499.00 27759228.00
 -18.14   1.67 -41.11 1615576499.00 27759282.00
 -18.33   1.52 -40.49 1615576499.00 27759335.00
 -18.30   2.81 -39.54 1615576500.00 27759388.00
 -18.63   2.18 -42.18 1615576500.00 27759447.00
 -19.01   1.27 -41.38 1615576500.00 27759500.00
 -18.56   1.78 -40.46 1615576500.00 27759553.00
 -18.59   3.46 -41.01 1615576500.00 27759606.00
 -19.37   4.40 -42.21 1615576500.00 27759660.00
 -18.69   3.70 -42.43 1615576500.00 27759713.00
 -18.30   1.56 -39.78 1615576500.00 2775976.00
 -18.71   3.93 -40.81 1615576500.00 27759819.00
 -18.81   4.17 -41.98 1615576500.00 27759873.00
```

Comment: Could you add more details about the "60 Hz" signal you are sampling? Ignoring the non-uniform sampling for a second, sampling at 20 Hz may allow you to recover a signal if its bandwidth is less than 10 Hz. Look for "bandpass sampling" in wikipedia and in this website.

Comment: bandpass (sub)sampling if you know your signal is within a bandwidth <10 Hz, compressive sensing for the more general case of a sub-nyquist sampled linear signal model.

Comment: @MBaz the signal I am sampling has an extremely low bandwidth, and should always be 60hz (transmission line EMF.) I will look up bandpass sampling. How does this combine with the problem of non-uniformity?

Comment: @MarcusMüller gotcha, because my signal has a bandwitdh <10hz I will look into bandpass sampling.

Comment: I had thought that you could do this by taking the time modulo 1/60, plotting things out, and fitting with a spline.  But you don't have enough precision on the logging time.  If you know this to a higher degree of certainty -- even one more decimal place -- the method may be useful.  If you do update your table with more precision, please make the thing easy to cut and paste.